Pandas None acting as Text inconsistently across PCs
I have a python script which works fine.  We have a new user who when they run the same script get different results in how it handles the keyword None.
The sample code is below and simply merges 2 data frames, but the issue is on how it applies the suffixes.
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
    'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18],
    'Parent': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

data2 = {
    'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
    'Sex': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F'],
    'Parent': [5, 6, 7, 8]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df.info()
df2.info()

df3 = df.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='Name', right_on='Name', suffixes=[None,'_j'])
df3.info()

The expected and correct output of df3.info() is:
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------    --------------  ----- 
 0   Name      4 non-null      object
 1   Age       4 non-null      int64 
 2   Parent    4 non-null      int64 
 3   Sex       4 non-null      object
 4   Parent_j  4 non-null      int64

However on the new user, they are getting per below.  As you can see, column 2 is 'ParentNone' not 'Parent'.  For some reason it is treating the suffix of None as the text 'None'.
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------    --------------  ----- 
 0   Name      4 non-null      object
 1   Age       4 non-null      int64 
 2   ParentNone    4 non-null      int64 
 3   Sex       4 non-null      object
 4   Parent_j  4 non-null      int64

We are both running the same install of python.  My pandas install is 1.4.4 but theirs is 1.4.2 but looking at GitHub for the merge function, there is no difference between the 2 versions of pandas.
Any ideas on what on earth could be making one install treat None as text?

Are you sure they're running the same script? That would happen if they used suffixes=['None','_j'] and I can't think of a reason why pandas would convert None to its string representation automatically.

Yep, they are 100% running the same script.

Well at least you can fix it easily: suffixes=['', '_j']
